# Replace "%20" with "-" in URL for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, url

I'm developing a web application using rails.
For aesthetic purposes, i need to replace %20 with -

Before: http://localhost:3000/movies/2006/Apna%20Sapna%20Money%20Money

After: http://localhost:3000/movies/2006/Apna-Sapna-Money-Money

Is there anyway i can achieve this in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id

this is the best way to go about seo urls

Comment: 404

There isn't a GitHub Page here.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`URI.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M009387) to break it into pieces and then change only the path component:

```
require 'uri'
u      = URI.parse(url)
u.path = u.path.gsub('%20', '-')
url    = u.to_s
```

Just a simple [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186) on the whole URL would probably work fine but a little extra paranoia might save you some confusion and suffering down the road. Also, if you're just replacing a literal string rather than a regular expression, you can use a String as the first argument to `gsub` and avoid some escaping issues:

> The *pattern* is typically a Regexp; if given as a String, any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally, e.g. `'\\d'` will match a backlash followed by `d`, instead of a digit.

Comment: where do i change this code? The video controller or routes.rb?

Comment: @Wen: You probably want to add a slug to your model and reference the model trough the slug. Do some googling for "rails slug" ad you should find some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

If your string is stored in the variable `url` you can use

```
url.gsub(/%20/, "-")
```

to return the string you want, or

```
url.gsub!(/%20/, "-")
```

to actually modify the value of `url` with the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be saving "Apna-Sapna-Money-Money" within your `Movies` model as an attribute (I usually call these `slug`s). Then, to generate these, you might just need to replace spaces in the movie title with hyphens. Something like:

```
class Movie
  before_create :generate_slug

  private
  def generate_slug
    slug = title.gsub(" ", "-")
  end
end
```

Then in your controller action you can simply do a `Movie.find_by_slug!(params[:id])` call.

Basically, there should be no reason for users to ever arrive at a URL with %20 in it...